# Java code to manipulate a string to a json format

Tags: java, json

```
String xtext = "#Samsung Electric Range with Fan Convection~86309930018~$525.00~TRUCK~0.0~R55856112#HAUL AWAY~07601000018~$24.99~TRUCK~0.0~R55856112#ELECTRIC RANGE C~88301170018~$21.99~TRUCK~0.0~R55856112";
```

Need sample to convert this string into json format as below.
Separators # for rows and ~ for columns comes in same pattern.
Note: I need to plug this code in **talend tjavarow** component. Appreciate in advance      .

```
{ "items":[{ "description":"Samsung Electric Range with Fan Convection",
             "id":"86309930018",
             "price": { "unitPrice":525.00 },
             "shipMethod":"TRUCK",
             "ivn":"R55856112",
             "quantity":0.0
           },
           { "description":"HAUL AWAY",
             "id":"07601000018",
             "price": { "unitPrice":24.99 },
             "shipMethod":"TRUCK",
             "ivn":"R55856112",
             "quantity":0.0
            },
            {
               "description":"ELECTRIC RANGE C",
               "id":"88301170018",
               "price": { "unitPrice":21.99 },
               "shipMethod":"TRUCK",
               "ivn":"R55856112",
               "quantity":0.0
            }
          ]
}
```

---

got this...

```
String str = "Samsung Electric Range with Fan Convection~86309930018~$525.00~TRUCK~0.0~R55856112#HAUL AWAY~07601000018~$24.99~TRUCK~0.0~R55856112#ELECTRIC RANGE C~88301170018~$21.99~TRUCK~0.0~R55856112";

String[] aStr;
String[] bStr;
String desc;
String id;
String price;
String shipMethod;
String ivn;
String quantity;

aStr = str.split("#");

for (String a : aStr ) 
 {
   System.out.println(a);
   
   bStr = a.split("~");  
   desc = bStr[0];
   id = bStr[1];
   price = bStr[2];
   shipMethod = bStr[3];
   ivn = bStr[4];
   quantity = bStr[5];
   
   System.out.println(desc+"|"+id+"|"+price+"|"+shipMethod+"|"+ivn+"|"+quantity);
   
   
 }
```

Comment: I suggest you to write some mapper

Comment: This question shows not even a minimum effort to have been resolved. This is a forum to find programming help, not to do your work/homework. Show what you have tried, where did you stuck and someone will be glad to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to chop up the string into arrays

```
String [ ] split ( String regex, int limit )
```

first pull out the string between # and ~
take the remainder string and split it using "~" as a delimiter

```
id = array[0]
price = array[1]
shipMethod = array[2]
ivn = array[3]
quantity = array[4]
```

then you can package it all up into json